# WSO2 Unit Test on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, wso2

So, I am trying to flesh out this CD/CI for WSO2 on Jenkins pipeline with a jenkinsfile. I have a multi maven project. This project has a simple unit test.

When I run a "mvn clean install" on the project's folder it works great, but when jenkins does it it fails to find a file.

I looked into the pluging's code and couldn't quite figure out where the path it tries to use comes from. Nevertheless, the path is valid, so I am guessing the context from where the path is being run is off, and since I don't know where that path is comming from, I can't force a full path.

Anyone ran into this problem before or have any idea on how to fix?

I will put some references below, let me know what else you need.

**Command used both in cmd prompt and jenkinsfile**

```
mvn -e -X clean install -DtestServerType=local -DtestServerPort=9008 -DtestServerPath=C:\\IntegrationStudio\\runtime\\microesb\\bin\\micro-integrator.bat"
```

**Maven log running cmd prompt**

```
[INFO] --- synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test (synapse-unit-test) @ HelloWorld ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=57600, ConflictMarker.markTime=33000, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=24, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=119400, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=16200, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=21, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=325500, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=24, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=149066200, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=572800}
[DEBUG] org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:jar:5.2.10
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.4:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.20:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.20:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>com.example.HelloWorld:HelloWorld:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:jar:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenTestSkip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerType = local
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerPort = 9008
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerPath = C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\bin\micro-integrator.bat
[DEBUG]   (f) server = org.wso2.synapse.unittest.SynapseServer@2160e52a
[DEBUG]   (f) testCasesFilePath = C:\Users\mpires\IntegrationStudio\workspace\HelloWorldMaster\HelloWorld\test\${testFile}
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] U N I T - T E S T S
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detect 1 Synapse test case files to execute
[INFO]
[INFO] Starting unit testing agent of path - C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\bin\micro-integrator.bat
[INFO] Waiting for testing agent initialization
[INFO]
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:35:25,603]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} - Synapse unit testing server enabled
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:35:25,616]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.unittest.UnitTestingExecutor} - Unit testing agent started
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:35:25,618]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.unittest.UnitTestingExecutor} - Synapse unit testing agent has been established on port 9008
[INFO] SynapseTestCaseFile C:\Users\mpires\IntegrationStudio\workspace\HelloWorldMaster\HelloWorld\test\helloWorldTest.xml tested successfully
```

**Maven Log from Jenkins**

```
[INFO] --- synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test (synapse-unit-test) @ HelloWorld ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=24700, ConflictMarker.markTime=18500, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=24, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=9500, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=17000, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=21, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=335600, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=24, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=112537900, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=427600}
[DEBUG] org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:jar:5.2.10
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.4:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.20:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.20:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>com.example.HelloWorld:HelloWorld:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:jar:5.2.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.wso2.maven:synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin:5.2.10:synapse-unit-test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenTestSkip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerType = local
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerPort = 9008
[DEBUG]   (f) testServerPath = C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\bin\micro-integrator.bat
[DEBUG]   (f) server = org.wso2.synapse.unittest.SynapseServer@1460c81d
[DEBUG]   (f) testCasesFilePath = C:\Jenkins\workspace\WSO2HelloWorldPipeline\HelloWorld\test\${testFile}
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] U N I T - T E S T S
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detect 1 Synapse test case files to execute
[INFO] 
[INFO] Starting unit testing agent of path - C:\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\bin\micro-integrator.bat
[INFO] Waiting for testing agent initialization
[INFO] 
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:22:20,457]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} - Synapse unit testing server enabled
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:22:20,498]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.unittest.UnitTestingExecutor} - Unit testing agent started
[DEBUG] [2020-01-28 10:22:20,499]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.unittest.UnitTestingExecutor} - Synapse unit testing agent has been established on port 9008
[error] Artifact data reading failed 

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '..\HelloWorld\src\main\synapse-config\api\helloWorld.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1711)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1748)
    at org.wso2.synapse.unittest.SynapseTestCaseFileReader.processTestArtifactData(SynapseTestCaseFileReader.java:126)
    at org.wso2.synapse.unittest.SynapseTestCaseFileReader.processArtifactData(SynapseTestCaseFileReader.java:82)
    at org.wso2.synapse.unittest.UnitTestClient.executeTests(UnitTestClient.java:50)
    at org.wso2.synapse.unittest.UnitTestCasesMojo.testCaseRunner(UnitTestCasesMojo.java:143)
    at org.wso2.synapse.unittest.UnitTestCasesMojo.execute(UnitTestCasesMojo.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

[error] Error in creating deployable message
[INFO] No test cases found in C:\Jenkins\workspace\WSO2HelloWorldPipeline\HelloWorld\test\helloWorldTest.xml unit test suite
```

**HelloWorld POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.HelloWorld</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>HelloWorld</name>
  <description>HelloWorld</description>
  <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>HelloWorldProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
   </parent>
  <properties>
    <CApp.type>bpel/workflow=zip,lib/registry/filter=jar,webapp/jaxws=war,lib/library/bundle=jar,service/dataservice=dbs,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,carbon/application=car,registry/resource=zip,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/endpoint=xml,web/application=war,lib/carbon/ui=jar,service/axis2=aar,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/configuration=xml,wso2/gadget=dar,lib/registry/handlers=jar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar,synapse/task=xml,synapse/api=xml,synapse/template=xml,synapse/message-store=xml,synapse/message-processors=xml,synapse/inbound-endpoint=xml</CApp.type>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <directory>target/capp</directory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>package</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>mvn</executable>
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>clean</argument>
                <argument>package</argument>
                <argument>-Dmaven.test.skip=${maven.test.skip}</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>mvn</executable>
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>clean</argument>
                <argument>install</argument>
                <argument>-Dmaven.test.skip=${maven.test.skip}</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>mvn</executable>
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>deploy</argument>
                <argument>-Dmaven.test.skip=${maven.test.skip}</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>synapse-unit-test-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>synapse-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>synapse-unit-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <server>
            <testServerType>${testServerType}</testServerType>
            <testServerHost>${testServerHost}</testServerHost>
            <testServerPort>${testServerPort}</testServerPort>
            <testServerPath>${testServerPath}</testServerPath>
          </server>
          <testCasesFilePath>${project.basedir}\test\${testFile}</testCasesFilePath>
          <mavenTestSkip>${maven.test.skip}</mavenTestSkip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>wso2-esb-api-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>api</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>pom-gen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactLocation>.</artifactLocation>
              <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, As I suspected the problem is caused by those pesky `..\` that causes the path to become invalid and as far as I know that's a bug in the pluging code because there's no reason for that to be.

The code was working when I ran on the console because I was inside HelloWorld, when I tried to run it from the same root that jenkins ran I would run into the same problems.

I opened a ticket at https://github.com/wso2/maven-tools/issues/51 and as a work around I split my maven command between a test run and a install without test and did the test run from inside the offending directory.

The downside of this workaround is that if you have more than one xml file you need to test this will very likely break.

workaround code:

```
dir(APP_NAME){

                    bat "mvn -e clean test -DtestServerType=local -DtestServerPort=9008 -DtestServerPath=C:\\IntegrationStudio\\runtime\\microesb\\bin\\micro-integrator.bat" //-Dmaven.test.skip=true" 
                }

                bat "mvn -e clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true"
```